# Loading comments from Database

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a simple forum for my php project. I have a viewpost.php file which displays all the posts and has a read more button.like this.

```
 <?php             
     foreach($rows as $output){
           echo '<div id="dd">';
                    $uid = $output['uid'];
                    $result2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE uid = '$uid'");
                $result2->execute();
                $rows2 = $result2->fetchAll();
                foreach($rows2 as $username_row){
                echo 'POST BY '.$username_row['username'].':';}
                    echo '<h3>Title:'.$output['title'].'</h4>';
                    ?>
  <form action="comments.php" method="post">
      <input type="submit" value="Read more" name="">
  </form>

  <?php
                    echo '</div>';
  }
?>
```

now I want to load post and comments in comments.php. but I want post_id to retrieve post,title and comments from the database. I wonder how to pass the post_id from viewpost.php to comments.php when the user clicks on the readmore button.any help will be really appreciable am a newbee.

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="$output[id]" />`, basically. And it would appear you're doing nested queries in a loop. You should re-write a single `JOIN`ed query instead.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for such an amazing solution.what did you actually mean when you said JOIN? . you are saying to join the two table first and retreive the columns?

Comment: if you're running two queries in a loop, and the "inner" query uses data from the "outer" query, then they should be re-written as a single query using `JOIN`. then you're running ONE query, instead of 1+n, which is very inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a input to your  form

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $output['id'] ?>" name="id" />
```

and in your comments.php file use `$_POST['id']`

or use URL like :

```
<a href="comments.php?id='<?php echo $output['id'] ; ?>'">
```

and in your comments.php file use `$_GET['id']`